# read big-endian data portably without inet.h

Tags: c, endianness

I'm parsing a file format that represents numbers in a big-endian way.

Normally I would include aarp/inet.h and use ntohl().

In various embedded c environments I use inet.h does not exist

Are there any standard equivalents to ntohl() I could use so I don't need to pull in inet.h?

Comment: The C standard does not require an implementation to have any endianness. For instance, you might have a C compiler targetting some decimal machine like the old IBM/1620

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Now sure why you wouldn't want to link in ntohl, but this should work, although a little slower than what your platform provides.

The code is optimized to use a compile time check to detect an Intel processor (which is always Little Endian).  You can amend that `#if defined...` block to include your own processor if you know it's endianness.  Otherwise, it falls back to doing a simple runtime check of detecting Little Endian.

```
#include <stdint.h> // if stdint.h is not available, then "typedef int int32_t" and "typedef unsigned int uint32_t" as appropriate

int compile_time_assert[(sizeof(int32_t) == 4)?1:-1];

int32_t NTOHL(int32_t value)
{

#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_IX86) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__x86_64) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__amd64) || defined(__amd64__)
        const int isBigEndian = 0;
#elif defined(sparc)
        const int isBigEndian = 1;
#else
        const int32_t test = 0x01020304;
        const char* ptr = (const char*)&test;
        int isBigEndian = (ptr[0] == 0x01);
#endif

    int32_t result = value;

    if (!isBigEndian)
    {
        uint32_t uvalue = (uint32_t)value; // cast to unsigned for shifting safely
        result = (uvalue >> 24) | ((uvalue >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) | ((uvalue << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | (uvalue << 24);
    }

    return result;
}
```

All of this assumes that the only two possible endianess architectures (big and little).  Which should be 99.9% of everything these days.  If you want this to work on an extremely dated architecture - one in which the old guys with the grey beards will speak about about 6-bit bytes, EBCIDIC, and 1's complements, you will need to modify the above code as appropriate.